# Move the "prefs" tab

Tags: feature-request, preferences

Currently, the order of tabs is "stats", "bounties", "prefs", "flair", "accounts".

The boring but important "prefs" shouldn't be exactly in the middle, to the left of the fun but non-vital flair. When scanning, people ignore stuff in the middle. It should be close to the left, or close to the right.

Moving it next to "accounts" might be preferable, as users may be tempted to look there when trying to change their settings, even though that isn't what "accounts" is about.